# Let $(X_t)$ be a continuous Markov chain and $\tau$ a stopping time. How to compute $\mathbb E [e^{-r\tau} \phi (X_\tau)]$?

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, markov-chains, stopping-times

Let $(X_t)$ be a continuous-time Markov chain on probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$ such that

- $X_0 = a$ almost surely.
- The state space $V$ is **finite** and endowed with discrete topology.
- The [infintesimal generator](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Infinitesimal_generator_(stochastic_processes)) is $L: V^2 \to \mathbb R$.

Moreover, we have $\phi: V \to \mathbb R_+$ and $D \subseteq V$. Consider the stopping time $$\tau = \inf \{ t \ge 0 \mid X_t \in D\}$$ Then I'm interested in computing $$\alpha = \mathbb E [e^{-r\tau} \phi (X_\tau)] \tag{1}$$

---

**My attempt:**

Let $Y = e^{-r\tau} \phi (X_\tau)$. Then $Y$ is a random variable defined by $$\forall \omega \in \Omega:Y (\omega) = e^{-r\tau(\omega)} \phi (X_{\tau(\omega)}(\omega))\tag{2}$$ It follows that $$\alpha = \int Y (\omega) \, \mathrm{d} \mathbb P (\omega) \tag{3}$$

---

In class, I'm given a random variable $Z$ with p.d.f $f$. Then I compute $\mathbb E[Z]$ by $$\mathbb E[Z] = \int zf(z) \, \mathrm{d}z \tag{4}$$, which is usually the Riemann integral.

This is the first time I'm required to compute the integral $(1)$. Could you please elaborate on how to compute $\alpha$ in $(1)$? Any reference is appreciated.

Comment: How is this different from the [Law of the Unconscious Statistician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician) giving $$\mathbb{E}[e^{-r\tau}\phi(X_\tau)] = \int_\mathbb{R} e^{-rt} \phi(X_t) f_\tau(t) dt,$$ where $f_\tau(\cdot)$ is the pdf of the stopping time $\tau$?

Comment: Related, not sure if duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3663541/let-x-t-be-a-continuous-markov-chain-and-tau-a-stopping-time-how-to-comp

Comment: @gt6989b I'm sorry for not being clear enough. I meant how to numerically compute $\mathbb{E}[e^{-r\tau}\phi(X_\tau)]$. From your formula, I think I must figure out how to compute $f_\tau(\cdot)$. Do you have any suggestion to approximate $\mathbb{E}[e^{-r\tau}\phi(X_\tau)]$?

Comment: I would try to look for the distribution function of your stopping time, that may be a doable problem depending on the specific details of $D$ etc.

Comment: @gt6989b Does the fact that $D$ and $V$ are finite make the calculation less cubersome?

Comment: Not necessarily. Imagine if $|V| = 10^{10}$ and $|D| = 10^9$...

Comment: @gt6989b I have edited my previous question, so it's not a duplicate anymore. If you don't mind, please suggest me some references [Reference for numerical evaluation of the expectation of a Markov chain at a stopping time](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3663541/reference-for-numerical-evaluation-of-the-expectation-of-a-markov-chain-at-a-sto).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I convert @gt6989b's comment as answer to close this question.

---

> How is this different from the [Law of the Unconscious Statistician](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician) giving $$\mathbb{E}[e^{-r\tau}\phi(X_\tau)] = \int_\mathbb{R} e^{-rt} \phi(X_t) f_\tau(t) dt,$$ where $f_\tau(\cdot)$ is the pdf of the stopping time $\tau$?