# Markov chain Monte Carlo with stopping time

Tags: numerical-methods, expected-value, markov-process, stopping-times, monte-carlo

I'm doing my thesis where I'm required to compute the numerical value in the following problem:

---

Let $(X_t)$ be a continuous-time Markov chain such that

- $X_0 = a$ almost surely.
- The state space $V$ is **finite** and endowed with discrete topology.
- The [infintesimal generator](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Infinitesimal_generator_(stochastic_processes)) is $L: V^2 \to \mathbb R$.

Let $D \subseteq V$ and consider the stopping time $$\tau = \inf \{ t \ge 0 \mid X_t \in D\}$$ Then I'm interested in computing $$\alpha = \mathbb E [X_\tau] \tag{1}$$

---

**Update:** I've found the algorithm to simulate $(X_t)$ as follows:

1. Initialize the state of the system $x_0 = a$.
2. For the given state $x$ of the system, calculate the transition rate $\lambda = -L(x,x)$.
3. Simulate holding time at $x$ by drawing from an exponential distribution with mean $1/ \lambda$.
4. Simulate the next state by drawing from the discrete distribution with probability $\mathbb P[\text{transition} = i] = L(x,i) / \lambda$ for all $i \neq x$.
5. Iterate steps 2-4.

---

I would like to ask how can we modify this algorithm to simulate the stopped process $X_\tau$. Thank you so much!

Comment: Why not just do the Monte-Carlo directly? In a discrete space $V$, model continuous transition by small discrete steps, compute the state transition matrix and you even can do steady state analysis in the usual way...

Comment: @gt6989b I've found the algorithm to simulate $(X_t)$ and update my question to reflect this. Could you please have a look at my new question and get me some suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the algorithm you have, and a condition defining $\tau$, i.e. the nature of $D$, simulate $X_t$ in small steps checking if $x_t \in D$ or not. Once $X_t \in D$ for the first time, you have found $\tau = t$.

Doing this for a large number of trials will get you the approximated pdf of $\tau$.

**UPDATE**

**(Q1) When to stop a particular trial:** 
One approach is to set a reasonable number of steps, and if you have not achieved it, record that. You will eventually have to make a call between calling this unreachable, or insufficient number of steps, but analysis of the transition matrix should tell you the point clusters.

**(Q2) Determining a reasonable number of trials:** This also is more of an art form that a science. When you see a clear pattern of convergence of the average, you can stop.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I have 2 concerns. Assume the current state is $x_{t'}$. (1) If the chain will never enter $D$ from this $x_{t'}$, then it will be an infinite loop. How can we tackle this problem? (2) How to determine an appropriate number of trials?

Comment: @LAD please see the update

Comment: Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: @LAD yw, glad to be of help

Comment: I know this maybe not polite, but If you don't mind, please have a look at this new [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3668970/how-hz-colorblue-alpha-sum-y-p-z-y-hy-follows-from-markov-proper).