# How $h(z)=\color{blue}{\alpha} \sum_{y} p_{z y} h(y)$ follows from Markov property?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, stopping-times

I'm reading the paper [On forward improvement iteration for stopping problems](http://mat.izt.uam.mx/profs/anovikov/data/IWSM2009/contributed%20papers/IWSM69.pdf) by Albrecht Irle:

> We consider a discrete homogeneous Markov process $(Z_{n})$ with respect to the underlying filtration. The measurable state space $(S, \mathcal{S})$ is finite. Let $g: S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be measurable and $\alpha \in (0,1]$. We look at the optimal stopping problem for $$X_{n}=\alpha^ng\left(Z_{n}\right)$$

Let

- $P_{z}, E_{z}$ denote $P(\cdot \mid Z_{0}=z), E(\cdot \mid Z_{0}=z)$ respectively.
- $E_{z} X_{\tau}$ exist for all stopping rules $\tau$ and all $z \in S$.
- $p_{z y}=P(Z_{1}=y \mid Z_{0}=z)$ for all $y, z \in S$.
- $\tau_{n}(B)=\inf \left\{j \geq n \mid Z_{j} \in B\right\}$ for a measurable $B \in \mathcal{S}$.
- $h_{i}(B)(z)=E_{z} \alpha^{\tau_{i}(B)} g\left(Z_{\tau_{i}(B)}\right)$ for $z \in S$ and $i \in \{0,1\}$.

Then the author present a proposition and its proof:

[image]

[image]

---

I'm trying to understand how to get $$\forall z \in S \setminus B:h(z)=\color{blue}{\alpha} \sum_{y} p_{z y} h(y)$$
We have\begin{aligned} h_{0}(B)(z) 
&= E_z \left [ \alpha^{\tau_{0}(B)} g\left(Z_{\tau_{0}(B)}\right) \right ]\\
&= \sum _{k=0}^\infty \alpha^{k} g\left(Z_{k}\right) P_z\left [ \tau_{0}(B) = k  \right ]\\
&= \sum _{k=0}^\infty \alpha^{k} g\left(Z_{k}\right) \sum_y P_z\left [  \tau_{0}(B) = k,X_1=y \right ] \\
&= \sum _{k=0}^\infty \alpha^{k} g\left(Z_{k}\right) \sum_y P_z\left [  \tau_{0}(B) = k \mid X_1=y \right ] P_z [X_1=y]\\
&= \sum _{k=0}^\infty \alpha^{k} g\left(Z_{k}\right) \sum_y P_y\left [  \tau_{0}(B) = k \right ] p_{zy}\\
&= \sum_y \left [ \sum _{k=0}^\infty \alpha^{k} g\left(Z_{k}\right) P_y\left [  \tau_{0}(B) = k \right ] \right ] p_{zy}\\
&= \sum_y E_y \left [ \alpha^{\tau_{0}(B)} g\left(Z_{\tau_{0}(B)}\right) \right ] p_{zy}\\
&= \sum_y h_{0}(B)(y) p_{zy}
\end{aligned}

In my attempt, I could not see how the constant $\color{blue}{\alpha}$ appears. Could you please elaborate on this point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\peq{\mathrel{\phantom{=}}{}}\def\tb{{τ_0(B)}}$Since $z \in S \setminus B$, then\begin{align*}
&\peq E_z\left( α^\tb g(Z_\tb) \right) = \sum_{k = \color{red}{1}}^∞ E_z\left( α^k g(Z_k) I_{\{\tb = k\}} \right)\\
&= \sum_{k = 1}^∞ \sum_{\color{red}{x \in B}} E_z(α^k g(x) I_{\{Z_k = x, \tb = k\}}) = \sum_{k = 1}^∞ \sum_{x \in B} α^k g(x) P_z(Z_k = x, \tb = k)\\
&= \sum_{k = 1}^∞ \sum_{x \in B} \sum_{y \in S} α^k g(x) P_z(Z_k = x, \tb = k \mid \color{red}{Z_1} = y) P_z(Z_1 = y).\tag{1}
\end{align*}
Note that $P_z(Z_1 = y) = p_{zy}$. For $y \in B$,$$
P_z(Z_k = x, \tb = k \mid Z_1 = y) = \begin{cases}
δ_{xy}; & k = 1\\
0; & k \geqslant 2
\end{cases},
$$
and for $y \in S \setminus B$,$$
P_z(Z_k = x, \tb = k \mid Z_1 = y) = \begin{cases}
0; & k = 1\\
P_y(Z_{k - 1} = x, \tb = k - 1); & k \geqslant 2\\
\end{cases},
$$
thus\begin{gather*}
\sum_{x \in B} \sum_{y \in S} α g(x) P_z(Z_1 = x, \tb = 1 \mid Z_1 = y) p_{zy}\\
= α \sum_{y \in B} p_{zy} g(y) = α \sum_{y \in B} p_{zy} E_y\left( α^\tb g(Z_\tb) \right),
\end{gather*}\begin{align*}
&\peq \sum_{k = 2}^∞ \sum_{x \in B} \sum_{y \in S} α^k g(x) P_z(Z_k = x, \tb = k \mid Z_1 = y) p_{zy}\\
&= \sum_{k = 2}^∞ \sum_{x \in B} \sum_{y \in S \setminus B} α^k g(x) P_y(Z_{k - 1} = x, \tb = k - 1) p_{zy}\\
&= α \sum_{y \in S \setminus B} p_{zy} \sum_{k = 2}^∞ \sum_{x \in B} α^{k - 1} g(x) P_y(Z_{k - 1} = x, \tb = k - 1)\\
&= α \sum_{y \in S \setminus B} p_{zy} \sum_{k = 1}^∞ \sum_{x \in B} α^k g(x) P_y(Z_k = x, \tb = k)\\
&= α \sum_{y \in S \setminus B} p_{zy} \sum_{k = 1}^∞ \sum_{x \in B} E_y(α^k g(x) I_{\{Z_k = x, \tb = k\}})\\
&= α \sum_{y \in S \setminus B} p_{zy} \sum_{k = 1}^∞ E_y(α^k g(Z_k) I_{\{\tb = k\}}) = α \sum_{y \in S \setminus B} p_{zy} E_y\left( α^\tb g(Z_\tb) \right)
\end{align*}
and\begin{align*}
(1) &= \sum_{x \in B} \sum_{y \in S} α g(x) P_z(Z_1 = x, \tb = 1 \mid Z_1 = y) p_{zy}\\
&\peq + \sum_{k = 2}^∞ \sum_{x \in B} \sum_{y \in S} α^k g(x) P_z(Z_k = x, \tb = k \mid Z_1 = y) p_{zy}\\
&= α \sum_{y \in B} p_{zy} E_y\left( α^\tb g(Z_\tb) \right) + α \sum_{y \in S \setminus B} p_{zy} E_y\left( α^\tb g(Z_\tb) \right)\\
&= α \sum_{y \in S} p_{zy} E_y\left( α^\tb g(Z_\tb) \right).
\end{align*}

Comment: I'm going to read your answer carefully tonight :))

Comment: I'm reading your answer. Could you please elaborate on which point that I got incorrect?

Comment: @LAD The mistake mainly occurs at$$E_z\left(α^{τ_0(B)}g(Z_{τ_0(B)})\right)=\sum _{k=0}^∞α^kg(Z_k)P_z(τ_0(B)=k),$$where the RHS has $g(Z_k)$, i.e. a random variable, outside the expection.

Comment: Thank you so much for your dedicated support. It seems that I've figured out another way to prove this proposition [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3676894/prove-that-value-function-u-satisfies-this-system-of-linear-equation). If you don't mind, please have a look at it.