# Let $(X_t)$ be a continuous-time Markov chain and $\tau$ the first jump time. Compute $\mathbb E_x [a^{\tau} \phi (X_\tau)]$

Tags: integration, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, expected-value, markov-process

Let $(X_t)$ be a continuous-time Markov chain such that

- The state space $V$ is **finite** and endowed with discrete topology.
- The [infintesimal generator](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Infinitesimal_generator_(stochastic_processes)) is $L: V^2 \to \mathbb R$.

Let

- $\alpha \in (0,1)$.
- $\phi$ be a function from $V$ to $\mathbb R_+$.
- $\tau$ is the first jump time, i.e. the first time that the chain makes a transition to a new state.

I would like to ask how to compute $$\alpha = \mathbb E_x [a^{\tau} \phi (X_\tau)]$$ where $\mathbb E_x := \mathbb E_x [ \cdot | X_0 = x ]$.

---

**My attempt:**

It's well-known that given $X_0$, $\tau$ is exponentially distributed with parameter $-L(X_0,X_0)$. Then

$$\alpha = \mathbb E_x [a^{\tau} \phi (X_\tau)] = -\int_0^\infty  a^s L(x,x)\phi (X_s) e^{-sL(x,x)} \mathrm{d}s$$

I'm stuck because there is $s$ inside $\phi(X_s)$. Could you please elaborate on how to compute $\alpha$?

Thank you so much!

Comment: The issue in the calculation is using the formula$$E(g(τ))=\int g(t)\,\mathrm dF_τ(t),$$ which requires that $g$ be a *deterministic* measurable function of $τ$, but $Χ_τ$ is not deterministically determined by $τ$.

Comment: @Saad you meant that it's hard to find a closed form of $\alpha$?

Comment: I'm not so familiar with continuous-time Markov chains, but I think there should exist a result similar to that in [How $h(z)=\color{blue}{\alpha}\sum_yp_{z y}h(y)$ follows from Markov property?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3668970).

Comment: Thank you so much @Saad! You got me an idea of apply that formula to this case :))

Comment: Hi @Saad, I can not believe that I apply your suggestion successfully to solve for $\alpha$. Everything combines perfectly. Math is beautiful. Infinite thanks for you :))))))

Comment: I'm glad to here that you find math to be beautiful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much for @Saad's invaluable comment! I post it here to close this question:

---

> The issue in the calculation is using the formula$$E(g(τ))=\int g(t)\,\mathrm dF_τ(t),$$ which requires that $g$ be a deterministic measurable function of $τ$, but $Χ_τ$ is not deterministically determined by $τ$.
>
> I'm not so familiar with continuous-time Markov chains, but I think there should exist a result similar to that in  [How $h(z)=\color{blue}{\alpha}\sum_yp_{z y}h(y)$ follows from Markov property?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3668970/how-hz-colorblue-alpha-sum-y-p-z-y-hy-follows-from-markov-proper).